# Whats the average Git backup time

Tags: linux, github

- How to know how long does it take for git to backup?
- Git backup is scheduled, the backup works, but how to check the amount of time it takes to backup?

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: What do you mean by "Git backup"? Git is a version control system, not a backup tool. And how can anybody comment on how long a backup takes "on average"? Backups are dependent on (a) the data you have, (b) the medium you're using, (c) network speed, if applicable, (d) your backup scheme (i.e. full, incremental, differential), (e) a bunch of other things. This question is unanswerable. Please take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and then read [ask].

Comment: What's a git backup?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute git backup with the command `time` to see how amount of time it takes the backup.

```
time <command>
```